# How to set array in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class field

```
char chars[4]
```

I want to init this field in the constructor.
My constructor need to get `char chars[]` as a parameter and in the constructor call I want to init my class fields.
Can I do it or I need to call copy?

Comment: Would you post some code showing what you want to do exactly in the constructor? If you are trying to use the initializer list to initialize the array, that is not possible. However, I can not understand your intention from the question.

Comment: In C++, you generally want to avoid built-in arrays, and use `std::string`, `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call copy.

```
MyClass::MyClass(const char* param)
{
  std::copy(param, param + 4, chars);
}
```

This is slightly risky code since there is no guarantee that param has four characters to copy.

Comment: Is there any simple alternative. Is there a difference between define the param in the constructor as char* to define as char array? Thank you

Comment: For a parameter `char*` is exactly the same as `char[]`, and `const char *` is exactly the same as `const char[]`. But only for parameters.

Comment: Can you please explain why only for char

Comment: No, not only for char, only for *parameters*. In a parameter `int*` is the same as `int[]` for instance. The reason is that you cannot pass an array as a parameter in C/C++. So the designers of C chose to use the array syntax to mean the same as a pointer for parameters. If you want to say `char[]` then do it like that. It won't make any difference.

Comment: what about passing a std::vector<char> by reference instead?

Comment: Alternatively you can pass the array by reference: `MyClass::MyClass( const char (&param)[4] )`, this will only let arrays of 4 characters. As for the actual answer, yes you need to `copy` the data.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::copy` like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    char m_x[4];    
public:
    MyClass(const char (&x)[4])
    {
        std::copy(x, x + 4, m_x);
    }
};
```

You should really be explicit with your types here to enforce that you pass exactly 4 elements.

Comment: Being explicit with the types here doesn't enforce *anything at all*. `MyClass(const char x[4])` is the same as `MyClass(const char* x)`.

Comment: It's not enforce but document the method by the signature, which is good

Comment: Edited so it does enforce. My bad.

Comment: Logically, you could actually accept a character array of any size greater than four.

Comment: Right; I went with the most literal interpretation of the original question. There's no way to know where the flexibility lies: in the passed-in type, or in the stored type. We don't even know what this variable is used for; most likely it's a string which makes most of the answers here worthless.

Comment: I had to make an edit to remove my downvote. Silly SO doesn't unlock my vote if you edit in the grace period. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't fully agree with the assumption that greater than 4 is good. It all depends on the domain and the design, and enforcing an exact size match might be the right approach. I tend to believe on strict interfaces...

Comment: I didn't say that it was good. I merely implied that you could.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to use a `vector<char>` which can be initialised in the initialiser list:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(char* a): a_(a, a + strlen(a)) {}
private:
    std::vector<char> a_;
};
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/x9p6I .

---

This could be made into a template to support different types but would require the number of elements in the array to be provided to the constructor (as `strlen()` would not be applicable to an array of `int`). For example:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(const T* a, const size_t count): a_(a, a + count) {}
private:
    std::vector<T> a_;
};
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/hhoaC .

Comment: And if `a` is not null-terminated? Because if it is, he's better to use `std::string`, right?

Comment: @tenfour, correct. About to update this as _what if an int array_ was mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood, you need to create `Conversion constructors`, it should looks like this:
`A::A(const char* string)
{strncpy(chars, string, 4);
}`

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You need to copy the contents from the input parameter.

Comment: It disgusts me that people post such things as answers to a C++ question.

Comment: strcpy_s takes 3 arguments, not two! This does not compile! and it's not C++

Comment: @john It shouldn't have been. The OP didn't even try the answer before accepting it.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I guess the OP really doesn't want to call `std::copy` for some reason.

Comment: I accept the answer because this is the best for char array. In these simple answers it's not matter if it compile because the answer is clear , so if there is compilation error you fix it by yourself.

Comment: @user1495181: Correct. Your question was if you need to copy, and my answer was yes. The code is just a supplementary info to prove the answer...